# ORDER BY apenas dia sem hora

Tags: mysql, sql, data, order-by, timestamp

No MySQL tenho uma coluna `timestamp` chamada `dia_cadastr`o (2016-06-21 11:27:32), na consulta quero dar um `ORDER BY` apenas no dia, e desconsiderar o horário. Ou seja, se tiverem produtos cadastrados no mesmo dia, depois ele da um `ORDER BY RAND()`

Tinha feito assim:

```
ORDER BY produto.dia_cadastro DESC, RAND()
```

Mas aí ele considerara o horário também.

Comment: Você esta fazendo o filtro pelo mês?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É só usar a função [`date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
ORDER BY date(produto.dia_cadastro) DESC, RAND()
```

A função pega apenas a parte da data sem o horário.

Só como curiosidade, se quiser só o dia do mês (esquisito) aí use [`day()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day):

```
ORDER BY day(produto.dia_cadastro) DESC, RAND()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/OrderByDate.sql).

É raro precisar ordenar só pelo dia, talvez para gerar estatística de dias de maior maior movimento.

Comment: Iria propor o DAY() , (esquisito) , só seria útil com um filtro.

Comment: Valeu, foi que foi!

Comment: Acredito que ele quis dizer que é esquisito verificar apenas o dia como descrito na pergunta, iria ignorar os meses e causaria problemas.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade se for isto, tá explicado então :) nem sei se causaria problemas, depende do problema, é raro alguém, em um conjunto de dados, ter que pegar o dia e ignorar o mês, o ano. pegar o dia serve mais pra fazer uma operação específica em um dado único, pra ordenar, e estranho, mas vejo algum caso pra isto. Pode ser estatística de dia mais movimentado, por exemplo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, @bigown. Como ele disse " apenas no dia, e desconsiderar o horário", deve ter sido a tentativa de tratar apenas a **data** do `datetime`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade acho que foi esta a intenção. O pessoa intercambia nomenclatura, o q até é normal, mas em programação pode trazer resultado errados :)